# mysql subsquery result as field

Tags: mysql, subquery, field

I'm trying to get results in just 1 row, any suggestion?

**Table Item**

```
idItem   idCampain    name
  1         1         Item1
  2         2         Item2
```

**Table ItemExtraField**

```
IdItemExtraField   idExtraFied  idItem   strValue
        1                  1       1        33
        2                  2       1        5
```

**Table ExtraField**

```
idExtraField   nameExtra    description  
     1          age            age  
     2         lifes           lifes
```

If I make a simple join:

```
SELECT A.*, C.nameExtra, B.strValue FROM Item A 
INNER JOIN ItemExtraField B ON B.idItem= A.idItem
INNER JOIN ExtraField C ON C.idExtraField = B.idExtraField 
where A.idCampain = 1
```

Got this results:

```
idItem  idCampain   name     nameExtra  strValue
  1        1        Item1      age        33
  1        1        Item1      lifes      5
```

But I need this:

```
idItem   idCapain   name   age    lifes
  1         1       Item1   33      5
```

I really tried many options but can't get the result like i need.
Any help is very appreciated.

**** EDITED ****

I found one solution:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
   CONCAT(
  'max(case when nameExtra= ''',
  nameExtra,
  ''' then strValue else NULL end) AS ',
  strExtra
)
) INTO @sql
FROM ExtraField A
INNER JOIN ItemExtraField B ON B.idItemExtraField = A.idItemExtraField ;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT L.*, ', @sql, ' 
              from Item L
              left join ItemExtraField CE
                on L.idItem = CE.idItem
              left join ExtraField C ON C.idExtraField = CE.idExtraField 
              group by L.idItem');

SELECT @SQL;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I used a procedure and it worked.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Your join criteria isn't strict enough.  Your `INNER JOIN ItemExtraField B ON B.idItem= A.idItem` will pull back both rows of the `ItemExtraField` table you provided, since both match the `idItem` of 1.  And both those rows join to exactly one row on the `ExtraField` table.  So that's why you get 2 rows.

An extra restriction on the `INNER JOIN` to the `ItemExtraField` table would eliminate the unwanted row.

It's hard to tell from just the information you provide exactly what you need, but this change would give you the result set you want for the data you provided.

```
SELECT A.*, C.nameExtra, B.strValue FROM Item A 
INNER JOIN ItemExtraField B ON B.idItem= A.idItem
    AND B.IdExtraItemField = A.idItem --Not sure how you would determine this criterion
INNER JOIN ExtraField C ON C.idExtraField = B.idExtraField 
where A.idCampain = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT A.*,
(
 SELECT C.strValue
 FROM ExtraField C
 inner join ItemExtraField B ON (B.idExtraField = C.idExtraField)
 WHERE nameExtra ='age' AND b.idItem = A.idItem
) age
From Item A
where A.idCampain = 1
```

Comment: I can't specify the row name, because each campaign can have different extras fields.
I found one solution but now I got an error when execute the query on phpMyAdmin

Comment: I'm not really sure you can get the results you want then. In order to spit out the rows as a column name like your example, I am pretty sure you *must* know the name going in. Without knowing, I think you will be limited to a query that returns two resultsets. one with the base data, and one with the extras fields